# Import errors on Android app after upgrading to Gradle 2.3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I have an Android app project on Android Studio which includes the following two import statements:

```
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.json.AndroidJsonFactory;
```

I have no problem with these imports when using Gradle plugin version 2.2.3. However, after upgrading to Gradle plugin 2.3.1, the statements show errors: 'extensions' turns red in both cases and the error says 'cannot resolve extensions'.

Here's some relevant background info:

Android Studio version 2.3.1

Gradle version 3.3

CompileSDKVersion 25

buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

Android SDK Tools Version 26.0.1

I've reported it as a bug to Google, but was wondering if anyone else has had similar problems, or can think of a possible explanation?

```
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0.rc2'
        compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Can you show your dependencies in `build.gradle`?

Comment: Edited to show dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see necessary dependency in your gradle file. Add this to your dependencies.

```
compile("com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
}
```

Comment: Adding this as a dependency fixes the import errors, but I now get a warning when the project builds:  WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.

Comment: I'm also curious why the import warnings only appeared after updating gradle to 2.3.1: the dependency you suggested wasn't there before the update, but there were no errors on the imports.

Comment: I'm not sure how your code compiled previously without appropriate dependency. It's not something that is being shipped with Android gradle plugin, thus it cannot affect.